# Header is displaying in next page in ALV report SAP ABAP

Tags: header, abap, alv

Here the function module `Z_DISPLAY_ALV` is a custom one, on that I don't have option for TOP-OF-PAGE.

```
      WA_HEADER-TYP = 'H'.
      WA_HEADER-INFO = 'Summary of History'.
      APPEND WA_HEADER TO T_HEADER.
      CLEAR WA_HEADER.

      CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_COMMENTARY_WRITE'
         EXPORTING
           IT_LIST_COMMENTARY = T_HEADER.

      CALL FUNCTION 'Z_DISPLAY_ALV'
       EXPORTING
        is_params = ls_params
       IMPORTING
        es_return = ls_return
       CHANGING
        ct_table  = ct_report.
```

Here is the code of the function module `Z_DISPLAY_ALV`:

```
FUNCTION z_display_alv.
*"*"Local Interface: 
*" IMPORTING 
*"   REFERENCE(IS_PARAMS) TYPE ZALV_PARAMS 
*" EXPORTING 
*"   REFERENCE(ES_RETURN) TYPE BAPIRET2 
*" CHANGING 
*"   REFERENCE(CT_TABLE) TYPE TABLE 

  DATA lo_alv TYPE REF TO lcl_alv_display. 

  CREATE OBJECT lo_alv EXPORTING is_params = is_params. 
  lo_alv->display( CHANGING ct_table = ct_table ). 
  es_return = lo_alv->ms_return. 

ENDFUNCTION.
```

The ALV is first displayed, but it doesn't show the header.

After I leave the ALV screen, the text `"Summary of History"` is then shown alone in the screen, but it's not what I want.

How to make `"Summary of History"` displayed above the ALV table, in the same screen ?

Comment: I guess your question is about the custom function module `Z_DISPLAY_ALV`, it's impossible to say anything because nobody knows it. Please read the help how to [complete your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @SandraRossi, FM code,
`FUNCTION z_display_alv.
*"*"Local Interface:
*"  IMPORTING
*"     REFERENCE(IS_PARAMS) TYPE  ZALV_PARAMS
*"  EXPORTING
*"     REFERENCE(ES_RETURN) TYPE  BAPIRET2
*"  CHANGING
*"     REFERENCE(CT_TABLE) TYPE  TABLE
  DATA lo_alv TYPE REF TO lcl_alv_display.
  CREATE OBJECT lo_alv
    EXPORTING
      is_params = is_params.
  lo_alv->display(
    CHANGING
      ct_table = ct_table
  ).
  es_return = lo_alv->ms_return.
ENDFUNCTION.`
Here, I am trying to add Top-of-Page on top of ALV Report
Let me know how I can add it here for Header.

Thank you !

Comment: Thx. I have merged your comment into the question and clarified it. But still, the code is incomplete because nobody knows your custom local class `LCL_ALV_DISPLAY`. General advice: why don't you add the required code in your custom code so that to pass the heading text and manage `TOP_OF_PAGE` event inside the local class?

Comment: to custom my code, it is used in several programs so i can't make any changes in custom function.
Thank you!

Comment: let me ask this question in simple way, I've student database there 10 records are available. I want to display summary who're all belongs to grade 1 and next grade 2 then grade 3 above the report. and need sending mail option as well. How to achieve in OO alv ? (not using grid alv)

Comment: Yes you can change it, but you feel the risk is too important. Such a change (adding an optional parameter and add conditioned processing) is usually not risky at all, with peer review to validate it. If you have other questions, ask them separately, Stack Overflow is not a "[(vampire) help forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)" it's a "[Q&A forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)", intended to also help future visitors.